# Merge two dataframe to reduce memory consumption

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to explode a list in my dataframe column and merge it back to the df, but i get a memory error while merging the flatten column with the initial dataframe. I would like to know if i can merge it in chunks, so that i can overcome the memory issue.

```
def flatten_colum_with_list(df, column, reset_index=False):
        column_to_flatten = pd.DataFrame([[i, x] for i, y in df[column].apply(list).iteritems() for x in y], columns=['I', column])
        column_to_flatten = column_to_flatten.set_index('I')
        df = df.drop(column, axis=1)
        df = df.merge(column_to_flatten, left_index=True, right_index=True)
        if reset_index:
            df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        return df
```

I would appreciate any support.

Comment: Can you show a small sample of your dataframes and the expected output? Maybe you can help us visualize how the merge is supposed to be performed. It's hard to tell with just the code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this, you can simply use the following code:

```py
df.explode(*column name here*,ignore_index=True)
```

The `ignore_index` set to true will set the index to 0,1,2,....... order.